# Passing constructors for outer dependency into Guice implementation

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice, factory

I have a Job, which should read data from deep storage. I am using Guice DI for my project.

There is a deep store already written and coming as an outer dependencie. I am struggling with instantiating the client in Guice

Here is the code

JobModule

```
public class JobModule extends AbstractModule {
  private Config config;

  JobModule(Config config) {
     this.config = config;
  }

  @Override
  protected void configure() {
    bind(Reader.class).to(DeepStoreReader.class);
  }

  @Provides
  @Named("config")
  Config provideConfig() {
    return this.config;
  }
}
```

Reader Interface

```
public interface Reader {
  List<String> getData(String path);
}
```

DeepStoreReader

```
public class DeepStoreReader implements Reader {
  private final DeepStoreClient deepStoreClient;

  DeepStoreReader(@Named("config") Config config) {
     this.deepStoreClient = new DeepStoreClient(config);
  }

  @Override
  public List<String> getData(String path) {
    return this.deepStoreClient.getData(path);
  }
}
```

The issue is I don't want to instantiate `DeepStoreClient` inside the `DeepStoreReader` constructor, because it becomes difficult to test `DeepStoreReader`, since I won't be able to mock `DeepStoreClient`

What is the preferred way to instantiate a client in such cases? DeepStoreClient is not a Guice module/implementation and is coming as an outer published dependency

PS: I am new to DI and learning Guice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is [constructor injection](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Injections#constructor-injection), e.g.:

```
@Inject
public DeepStoreReader(DeepStoreClient deepStoreClient) {
    this.deepStoreClient = deepStoreClient;
}
```

Guice will take care of instantiating the `DeepStoreClient` for you.

**EDIT:**

If `DeepStoreClient` itself has dependencies, you can also annotate that constructor:

```
@Inject
public DeepStoreClient(@Named("config") Config config) {
    // ... 8< ...
}
```

Comment: What if the DeepStoreClient takes an argument in the constructor? Let me edit the example

Comment: But, DeepStoreClient is an outer published dependency, and is not a Guice module/implementation

Comment: In that case, you might want to look into using [@Provides](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/ProvidesMethods) instead.

Comment: But, Provides would have to be defined in the Module, and DeepStoreClient is very specific to DeepStoreReader implementation. Isn't that contradicting separation of concerns?

Comment: If that is a concern, you could make use of a private submodule for `DeepStoreReader`. The [Guice wiki](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki) will have more information.

Comment: Forgot to mention, the [javadocs](https://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/index.html?com/google/inject/PrivateModule.html) are pretty good also with examples to follow.